# keras layer restart a part of the weights each epoch

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I am looking for a way to restart a random part of the weights of a layer each epoch (or every n epochs), I found [this](https://www.codementor.io/nitinsurya/how-to-re-initialize-keras-model-weights-et41zre2g) explaining how to re initialize a layer. I could use

```
weights = layer.get_weights()
```

and then using numpy operation in order to re init a part of the weights, or create a dummy layer extracting new initialized weights from it and use them with set_weights. I am looking for a more elegant way to just initialize a certain (or random) part of my weights in a layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras has [set_weights](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/) method to set the weights of the layer. To reset the weights of the layer at each epoch use call backs.

```
class My_Callback(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_begin(self, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        layer_index = 0  ## index of the layer you want to change
        # random weights to reset the layer
        new_weights = numpy.random.randn(*self.model.layers[layer_index].get_weights().shape)

        self.model.layers[layer_index].set_weights(new_weights)
```

### Edit:

To reset random n weights of a layer, one can use numpy to get random indexes to reset. Now the code would be

```
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        layer_index = np.random.randint(len(self.model.layers)) # Random layer index to reset
        weights_shape = self.model.layers.get_weights().shape
        num = 10 # number of weights to reset
        indexes = np.random.choice(weights_shape[0], num, replace=False)   # indexes of the layer to reset
        reset_weights = numpy.random.randn(*weights_shape[1:]) # random weights to reset the layer

        layer_weights = self.model.layers[layer_index].get_weights()
        layer_weights[indexes] = reset_weights
        self.model.layers[layer_index].set_weights(layer_weights)
```

Similarly to reset random `p %` of weights of a layer, first numpy can be used to select `p %` indexes of layer weights.

```
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        layer_index = np.random.randint(len(self.model.layers)) # Random layer index to reset
        weights_shape = self.model.layers.get_weights().shape
        percent = 10 # Percentage of weights to reset
        indexes = np.random.choice(weights_shape[0], int(percent/100.) * weights_shape[0], replace=False)   # indexes of the layer  to reset
        reset_weights = numpy.random.randn(*weights_shape[1:]) # random weights to reset the layer

        layer_weights = self.model.layers[layer_index].get_weights()
        layer_weights[indexes] = reset_weights
        self.model.layers[layer_index].set_weights(layer_weights)
```

Comment: as stated in the OP - I need to re init a part of the layer, and would prefer not using set_weights... Is there any other solution?

Comment: There are two ways to set the weights of a layer.   
1. using `layer.set_weights()` method or 
2.`model.set_weights()` method. Keras does not provided another way to change the weights of the layer.

Comment: can you please edit the answer so it will allow to restart a part of the weights of a layer?

Comment: could you be more specific? what do you mean by part of the weights of layer?

Comment: Random n weights, or random p precent of them